# What is the meaning of the TCP dump

Tags: tcp

What does the below mean?

12:07:44.267421 IP 157.200.123.194.57139 > 66.198.181.181.80: S 2606686013:2606686013(0) win 8192

Comment: wireshark will tell you

Answer (score 1):

Every field can be explained as bellow:

**12:07:44.267421** - *Timestamp*

**IP** - *Protocol*

**157.200.123.194.57139** - *Hostname/IP (157.200.123.194) and source port (57139)*

**66.198.181.181.80** - *Hostname/IP(66.198.181.181) and destination port (80)*

**S** - *First character of the TCP flag: PSH, RST, SYN, FIN (In this case, SYN)*

**2606686013** - *Initial sequence number from source*

**2606686013** - *Ending sequence number, which is the initial sequence number plus the size of the packet in data bytes*

**(0)** - *Data bytes or payload size of this packet*

**win 8192** - *Size of the receiving data window*

Answer (score 0):

Timestamp, Protocol, Source IP.Port, Destination IP.Port, TCP Flag, Sequence Number, Window size.

Answer (score 0):

At 12:07:44 (time) there's a TCP SYN packet (S) from 157.200.123.194 port 57139 to 66.198.181.181 port 80, sequence number 2606686013 with advertised window 8192